# PascalScript including other script per uses or include command

Tags: delphi, pascalscript

I have included the PascalScript engine into my software. My user now wants to write a whole set of scripts for this engine, and would like to know if it is possible to include other Scripts by an `include` or `uses` commmand.

What he wants to do is write one script that holds all kinds of constants/variables and another that does the logic. In the end he wants to include the constants into his logic script.

I hope this was clear enough to understand.

Comment: JVCL JvInterpreter does allow you to use other units, and can read them from files, try it instead if it matches your needs better.

Comment: Thanks for your hint Warren. I found the solution for pascal script see below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out, heres how how do to it:
The UsePreprocessor Property of the PascalScript compiler needs to be set to true. If so you can now use the following preprocessor command:

{$I filename.txt}

Also you need to implement the OnNeedFile Event of the compiler with something like the following example that I found on the net:

```
function TForm1.ceNeedFile(Sender: TObject; const OrginFileName: String;
var FileName, Output: String): Boolean;
var
  path: string;
  f: TFileStream;
begin
  Path := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + FileName;
  try
    F := TFileStream.Create(Path, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  except
    Result := false;
    exit;
  end;
  try
    SetLength(Output, f.Size);
    f.Read(Output[1], Length(Output));
  finally
    f.Free;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

(Please fix your question title)

I'm not entirely sure but afaik Pascalscript has no "file" concept. You could simply concat both parts before passing them to the interpreter, or have a small preprocessor look for the {$I } include statements and look the code to insert up.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the conditional define to `PS_USESSUPPORT`
and in the `OnFindUnknownFile` event you have to load the pas-file content
into the output string.

Then you can use "Uses XYZ;".